# django - How to manually set sys.path?

Tags: django

Till now I was making change on my django production server (yes, really really bad :p ). I am wanna to go to a git process, and creating a local test server before deployement. So, I downloaded my python files, and ran a :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

hoping and prayed... but it was not enough, I got a nice error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'issc.issc.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module: 'No module named issc.wsgi'
```

I read in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/) that [manage.py] is created automatically and sets up several key parts :

```
In addition, manage.py is automatically created in each Django project. manage.py is a thin wrapper around django-admin.py that takes care of several things for you before delegating to django-admin.py:
  It puts your project’s package on sys.path.
    It sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file.
    It calls django.setup() to initialize various internals of Django.
```

My question is : how can I manually set up these variables ? Because in my case I downloaded all the files on an arbitrary directory, but it was not enough. Eveything is here, but it is missing the link to this everything....

Comment: you don't need to set `os.path`, you need to set `sys.path`.

Comment: But actually you probably want to fix your code (I'm assuming `issc.wsgi` is your code) so everything gets loaded normally. You shouldn't need to put code on your path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually set the address of your config file, you can set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with the following:

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='settings_to_load'`

You can set all your environmental variables this way and it should work. I recommend to use a Virtualenv to this at least.